# Error BCE0043,BCE0044 and UCE001

Tags: unity, javascript, scripting, unityscript

I got my code right here:

```
#pragma strict

var hSliderValue : float = 0.0;

function OnGUI(){
hSliderValue = GUI.HorizontalSlider (Rect (25, 25, 100, 30),hSliderValue, 00, 1.0);
GetComponent<AudioSource>().volume=hSliderValue;
}
```

I don't know why those errors keep popping-up but unity say it have something to do with the: GetComponent().volume=hSliderValue;

BCE0043: Unexpected token: ).

BCE0044: expecting ), found '.'.

UCE0001: ';' expected. Insert a semicolon at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
GetComponent<AudioSource>().volume=hSliderValue;
```

This line is C#, not Javascript, or UnityScript.